# Create a div and give it a CSS entry?

Tags: javascript, css

In javascript I `document.createElement("div")` and I want to give it all the properties from an entry in a `CSS` file. I tried `newdiv.setAttribute("id","panelstyle")` but it did not set the style from that. Will I have to type out each individual `.style.property=` or is there a way to "setCSSProperties=panelstyle"?

Comment: What if you create a set of rules with a class name in CSS and apply the class to the `div`? It will save you a good amount of efforts.

Comment: panelstyle is a rule in your css file? is it defined as id?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Be sure to include all necessary details in your question. In this case, it's fairly obvious that in order to help you, we need to know what the rule you want applied to the div looks like.

Comment: As Damian said, do you have a #panelstyle rule in your CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use code as below and in css use `#` with your `id` attribute..**

(I think you forgot `document.body.appendChild(newdiv);`)

```js
var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
newdiv.setAttribute("id", "panelstyle");
```

```css
#panelstyle {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I had learned to set the styles before appending, but turning it around worked.

Comment: Doesn't matter which order you set the style or append the element, so long as you do both @Edward

Comment: No, really. `setAttribute` before `appendChild` did nothing, but turning it around did what I wanted.

Comment: @Edward Next time, post a [mcve] and you would get an answer showing that is not needed. Just swap the last 2 lines in above sample and you'll see it works.

Comment: I'll do that in 3 minutes. No, really, I have to wait 10 minutes after the post to check as answered.

Comment: fine... happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

CSS rules are defined with *selectors* that indicate what elements they apply to. For instance, this rule applies to all `div` elements:

```
div {
    color: green;
}
```

This one only applies to an element with `id="foo"`:

```
#foo {
    color: blue;
}
```

This one applies to all elements with the class `bar`:

```
.bar {
    color: red;
}
```

Selectors can be complex, for instance: Only `div` elements with class `bar`:

```
div.bar {
    color: yellow;
}
```

You can have the same rule apply to more than one set of elements. For instance, this rule applies to all `div` elements and also to any other element with class `foo`:

```
div, .foo {
    color: #eee;
}
```

So for you to apply a rule to your new element, you make the element match the rule's selector (and/or update the rule's selector so it will match the element).

Here's an example which styles your element in two different ways (because it's a div, and because it has `id="panelstyle"`):

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "I'm the div";
div.id = "panelstyle";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

```css
div {
  color: green;
}
#panelstyle {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```